# why is my nav not centred like everything else

Tags: html, css

just trying to make everything centred and clean.  Everything seems to be, apart from my nav bar at the top which seems to stick to the right ?

I can't figure out why?

Thank you

html
..............

```
    <div id="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#landing">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li>Musician</li>
            <li><a href="#instagram">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

                    <!-- BELOW THE NAV  -->

<div id="landing">

    <br><br><br> <p>more content</p>


</div>
```

............

CSS

.............

body { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; color: white;

```
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;


}
```

div#container {

margin: 0 auto;

}

div#nav {

```
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: top;

    display: inline-block;
```

}

li {

```
    display: inline;
```

}

div#landing {

```
background-image: url('rose1.png');
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

not sure why the nav is floating to the right ?

Comment: you can put width: 100%; in your div#nav, can you post the website link? i just saw that body css ain't 100% either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
div#nav {
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few **CSS** changes. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Remove `display: inline-block;` and add `width: 100%;` in `div#nav`.

```
div#nav {
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also remove default `padding-left` from `ul`.

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
body { 
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace; color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#nav {
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

div#landing {
    background-image: url('rose1.png');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#landing">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li>Musician</li>
            <li><a href="#instagram">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

                    <!-- BELOW THE NAV  -->

<div id="landing">

    <br><br><br> <p>more content</p>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the div#nav CSS block just remove the position property:

```
div#nav {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hi, this worked but i wanted the nav in fixed position, sorry i didnt explain that